# WAMP Server: phpMyAdmin showing loads of Deprecation Notices & errors?

Tags: php, windows, phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

I'm working with WAMP Server for local development, As WAMP does not ship with PHP 7.1, I installed it manually as I needed that version for a project to work.

I downloaded the binaries from the PHP site (Thread Safe version) and placed it inside `wamp64/bin/php/php7.1.8` and renamed the php.ini for development file to phpForApache.ini and had to change the extension dir for modules to load also.

After all of that I went on phpMyAdmin and here is an example:
[image]

There is many more errors of the same type.

My question is how do I solve them?

I am running 4.6.4 for phpMyAdmin...

Comment: WAMPServer has ADDON's for all current and lots of old releases of PHP. See http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/

Comment: There are also up to date versions of phpMyAdmin on that repo page also installable as ADDON's

Comment: Assuming you have WAMPServer 3 installed

Comment: Upgrade to phpMyAdmin 4.7.3 [ADDON for WAMPSevrer 3 Available here](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/)

Answer (score 2):

These errors came mostly cause of your phpMyAdmin version is not compatible with php version please first sure the cause of issue.

[image: phpMyAdmin-compatiblity-warning]

So you have to download the latest version of phpMyAdmin [phpMyAdmin-download-link](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/)

Download the latest version from upper right green button
[image: download-button]

Then extract that zip file in `wampp/apps` directory and remove `all-languages` from folder name and remove `-` from behind the version number this is not necessary but doing this to set a conventional name which will help us while we changing version number in files.

Copy `config.inc.php` file from older version folder and paste in new version folder which one you extract.

Edit phpMyAdmin version in `phpmyadmin.conf` file found in `wamp/alias` directory.

[image]

Edit `wampmanager.conf` file found in `wampp/` directory if you found phpMyAdmin version defined in this file because I am not sure probably they removed it from latest version of wamp.

Hop you found this helpful if yes please vote, happy codding